# count how many times a key has ans="true" in objects in side an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**I have this array.**

```
array (size=5)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[37]
          public 'options' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
          public 'answer_check' => string 'false' (length=5)
          public 'justify_answer' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
          public 'score' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'admin_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          public 'approved' => string 'approve' (length=7)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[38]
          public 'options' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
          public 'answer_check' => string 'true' (length=4)
          public 'justify_answer' => string 'test 2' (length=6)
          public 'score' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'admin_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          public 'approved' => string 'approve' (length=7)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[39]
          public 'options' => string 'test 3' (length=6)
          public 'answer_check' => string 'true' (length=4)
          public 'justify_answer' => string 'test 3' (length=6)
          public 'score' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'admin_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          public 'approved' => string 'approve' (length=7)
```

### What I want to do is

How many times **answer_check = "true"**

Without using loops.

Is there any way to it?

Comment: did you try array_column()?

Comment: no i didn't tryed array_column()

Comment: @M.Hemant wow! i didnt know about that function!! HOW?? I do now and it's great.

Comment: @ArslanAhmad look at this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-array_column-function/ it has a good example about half way down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filter array` and then `count` number of values in it:

```
echo count(array_filter(
    $array, 
    function($v) { return $v->answer_check === 'true'; }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner code. Combining `array_column` and `array_count_values`.

```
echo array_count_values(array_column($array, "answer_check"))["true"];
```

Comment: Element are object and not array so not all PHP version can do `array_column`

Comment: Run's fine, even as objects... http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z5yg-mfnh